# Python celery creates a lot of connections on redis

Tags: python, redis, celery

I am trying to make internet service using redis and celery.
My redis instance is tied to 10 simultaneous clients. When I am trying to run just one worker it initiates 6-9 connections for some reason (I see this on my redis admin panel). After some time it starts throwing 'max clients reached' error.
Is this expected behavior that worker is using so many connections? Should I switch to rabbitmq?

```
config = Configuration(None, EnvironmentType.beta, '../configuration.json')
 
beta_broker = Celery('src.beta_module', broker=config.celery_redis_url, include=['src.beta_module.notifications'])



 
 
def main():
    beta_broker.start(argv=['celery', 'worker', '-E', '--concurrency=1', '--loglevel=DEBUG'])
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**UPDATED**

I tried to set up redis_max_connections, but it does not help

```
    beta_broker = Celery('src.beta_module', broker=config.celery_redis_url, include=['src.beta_module.notifications'])
    beta_broker.conf.redis_max_connections = 2
```

broker_pool_limit = 0
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
'max_connections': 20,
}

still creates 8 connections to redis

Is there any way to disable receiving results of the tasks? I don't need this functionality anyway. Maybe it will help to reduce the number of connections?

**UPDATED**

After about 3 days of researching and reading numerous blogs and docs I decided to switch to rq

Answer (score 0):

have you tried set max connections for redis connetion pool with celery? https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#redis-max-connections

`redis_max_connections` - Default: No limit.

Comment: Does not help. I still see big number of clients. Check my updates in post

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
beta_broker.conf["broker_transport_options"] = {'fanout_prefix': True,
                                                'fanout_patterns': True,
                                                'max_connections': 2,
                                                'socket_keepalive': True},
beta_broker.conf["broker_pool_limit"] = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, I will try this definetely, but I decided to switch to RQ. Found it more simple and covenient for me.

Comment: Yea, if you want simple then Huey (https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or RQ are worth trying... Celery is IMHO much more powerful and flexible (user can write implementation of any major Celery feature - we already have our own autoscaler, scheduler, monitoring, etc).